# ASP.net MVC строго типизированное представление

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Делаю интернет магазин по сайту http://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/gamestore/level2/2_1.php

И стопорнулся на том, что не получается создать строго типизированное представление.

Нажимаю добавить представление => Пустую модель => Класс модели

Но там не могу найти модель, в частности, класс Game. только две модели.

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, в чём моя ошибка.

Comment: а Вы сделали построение решения после добавления третьего класса?!

Comment: да делал! я запускал приложение и поробавал так посмотреть может появиться!  показывается только две модели! Я низнаю я бы скинул вам скриншот но низнаю как здесь это сделать!

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вам необходимо указать полное имя типа, то есть вместе с пространством имен. Однако даже если это не получится, большой проблемой это не является - просто создайте представление без модели, а потом впишите в него тип модели, также с пространством имен. Например:

```
@model YourNamespace.YourModelModel
```

Comment: спасибо вообще это помогло! но можете обьяснить где и как указать это полное имя простанства имен?

Comment: @Ildarik07 укажите его первой строкой в файле представления

Comment: ну а вы не можете сказать по какой причине у меня не получается настроить строго типизированное представление автоматически?

Comment: обычно делается сначала модель, потом метод в контролере, а уже потом ПКМ на метод и Create View